# In C#, can value be extracted using AS keyword? How?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, typechecking

I have written the following code :

```
        object obj = 123; // Line 1
        int? num = null; // Line 2
        num = obj as int; // Line 3
```

I am getting compile time error in Line 3 as - "the as keyword must be used with reference type or nullable type('int' is a non-nullable value type)".

I want to understand:
1. Though my int is nullable, why then is it giving this error
2. How can we get the value of obj in num? Won't AS keyword work here?

Answer (score 4):

`Int?` And `int` are two different types.

Change

```
    num = obj as int; // Line
```

To

```
   num = obj as int?;
```

for readability, you may even write:

```
 Nullable<int> num;
 num = obj as Nullable<int>;
```

I'm going to extend this a little more and say, how do you get the value from a nullable object. Well, here's one way.

```
object obj = 123;
int? num;
num = obj as int?;
int myNumericValue = default(int);
If (num.HasValue) myNumericValue = num.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work....

```
num = obj as int; // Line 3
```

...the `as` operator must be able to return `null` if `obj` cannot be cast to `int`. But `int` cannot store a null, so it results in an error.

You have two alternatives:

**1. Use nullable int**

```
int? num;
num = obj as int?;
```

**2. Use a little more code**

```
int num;
num = (obj is int) ? (int)obj : default(int);
```